# what is the name of this thing in pine script

Tags: pine-script

[image]

I want to make a similar summary of information but I can not find how to do it

Comment: You have to create a table yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it using a label or a table and pretty much build it within a string using \n for new lines. or you can build it in an array and use `array.join(arr,\n)` you may not have to do the `\n` but im pretty sure you do.. that info box would probably be best built in an array with each index acting as a separate line in the info box.. it wouldn't be as hard as it looks most of those are built in strategy functions

[Example Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UG2q.png)

hope this helps